# Not refreshing iframe when refreshing whole page

Tags: iframe, refresh, page-refresh, partial-page-refresh

I have a page that contain an iFrame and a button that refreshs that iFrame and it's working as well as needed. What I am trying to do is not to allow the iFrame to be refreshed when refreshing the whole page is there anyway to do this?

Comment: why don't you want it refreshed and in which scenario you would like it to be refreshed ?

Comment: hello, inside the iFrame I have a timer this timer is updated when clicking the button in other word when refreshing the frame so when I refresh the whole page the timer is also updated which I don't want to. Thanks.

Comment: what about my second question ? what if the user closes the  window and then re-opens it ? it sounds to me that what you really want to do is to use the session or other server-side method to implement the timer.

Comment: The timer values are stored in a database so even if the user closes the page and reopens it the timer still works as. For me the problem I am trying to solve is that in order to update the timer when trying to call the function from button onclick it doesn't work but when putting it at the end of the code and being called on refresh it works. So that's why I am trying to work in this way.

Comment: You can't update the timer in the DB from JS - you'll have to use AJAX for that

Comment: One more thing in the database the timer is being updated as I want but what I need is the timer to be updated visually on the webpage for the user when changing the values in the database and this is done as I can see only by refreshing the page.